# Do Strategy Center bonus apply to non US units?

Tags: command-and-conquer-generals

If I capture Strategy Center, do the bonuses (Bombardment, Search and Destroy, Hold the Line) apply for GLA or China units?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they do.

In fact they even have stacked bonuses if you capture multiple SCs.

Sad truth is that only an AI will allow you to capture a Strategy Center or any buildings for that matter :)